# String.Format in Double Quotes in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is anybody  can help me with `string.Format` for below line. In '2056' I need to pass as {0}.

```
string body = @"{""idTimeSerie"":""2056"",""idTso"":-1}";
```

Due to double quotes I can't get it to execute.

I've tried in this way but no success.

```
string body = string.Format
                    (@"{""idTimeSerie"": "" \"{0}\" "",""idTso"":-1}", countryID);
```

Comment: try escaping the curly braces { to {{

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to escape the curly braces

> replace { to {{

```
string body = @"{{""idTimeSerie"":""2056"",""idTso"":-1}}";
```

Edit : [From MSDN - Another way of Escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a
>   format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display
>   a literal opening brace or closing brace. Specify two opening braces
>   ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two
>   closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}"). Braces in a
>   format item are interpreted sequentially in the order they are
>   encountered. Interpreting nested braces is not supported.

```
int value = 6324;
string output = string.Format("{0}{1:D}{2}", 
                             "{", value, "}");
Console.WriteLine(output);
// The example displays the following output: 
//       {6324}
```

Comment: I've tried with string literal but don't know why it doesn't work...But using double {{ brackets it zoomeddd...:-)

Comment: @allonhadaya  , my respect  ,yes this solution does not use the string format , if you look at the code , developer tried with and without string format but used verbatim string @ and he could not figure out the problem of escaping braces. once he figured that out , rest of the problem is piece of cake . I like your MSDN link

Comment: @simplecoder actually, he explicitly asked for a string.Format solution... `anybody can help me with string.Format for below line. In '2056' I need to pass as {0}` Your answer does not allow him to pass in the `countryID` as with string.Format({0}) etc...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`string body = string.Format(@"{{ ""idTimeSerie"": ""{0}"", ""idTso"": -1 ", countryID) + "}";`

Explanation:

1)
When using the @ flavor of string literals, double quotes are indicated by `""` (two consecutive double quotes).

[See MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
@"""Ahoy!"" cried the captain." // "Ahoy!" cried the captain.
```

2)
Use `{{` and `}}` to indicate a literal `{` and `}` respectively in your string format.

[See MSDN (Escaping Braces):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

> Specify two opening braces ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}").

Comment: I've tried different as you said but no use...string body =string.Format(@"{""idTimeSerie"": """"{0}"""",""idTso"":-1}", countryID);

Comment: `string.Format(@"""idTimeSerie"":""{0}"",""idTso"":-1", 2056)` works.

Comment: Try the updated solution. I didn't notice the single curly brace the first time.

Comment: Sorry again. I finally stopped being lazy and tried compiling and running it. There was an issue with nested braces so I brought the closing literal brace outside of the string format.

Comment: @allonhadaya I've tried this way and works mate...see the solution string body = string.Format(@"{{""idTimeSerie"": ""{0}"",""idTso"":-1}}", countryID); Anyhow thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
string body = string.Format("{{\"idTimeSerie\":\"{0}\",\"idTso\":-1}}", countryID);
```

Comment: have you tried running this? You may get an InvalidFormatException due to nested curly braces. (I did using mono)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a verbatim string in this case. I suspect you want:

```
string body = string.Format("{\"idTimeSerie\":\"{0}\",\"idTso\":-1}", countryID);
```

Comment: @simplecoder Correct, but I am not using a verbatim string in this example am i... ?

Comment: @simplecoder You have to escape { to {{ for the sake of `String.Format()`, not verbatim string literal. See my answer.